# Access to tunnel VPN from another network

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, nat

Here's the description of my problem :

I've a VPN LAN-to-LAN between my company and a customer. My subnet is `192.168.37.0/24`. The tunnel works perfectly.
But, I want to access to my customer network from an another network. The another network has this subnet : `192.168.33.0/24`. How to configure it ?
The connection between my two networks are OK.

I've a `Cisco ASA 5510`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

don't worry to be french, i'm italian.........

now, there are multiple ways to reach the goal; at least

1) static (pre-nat-interface-name,post-nat-interface-name) fake-addr real-addr links 2 addresses, one in each network, and perform a static 1:1 translation

2) anything coming from X and going to Y? well give it a global address so that you need 3 elements

2.1) an access-l defining the pertinent traffic
2.2) a global address to use for PAT
2.3) a link between them, as in NAT command

that ways allow (simply) you to translate one addr into another and vice-versa or multiple addresses to just one (second solution)

while the NAT (or PAT) addr belongs to the "right" (encapsulated) network you've reached the goal.

Answer (score 0):

it's a nonsense question without details.

suppose YOUR ASA defines traffic between your and customer networks (let's say represented by 192.168.37.0/24 and 10.20.30.0/24) and 192.168.33.0/24 is NOT coming out from a VPN but is a local network.

you can't just send pkt from 192.168.33.12 to 10.20.30.65 because the source is not included into "encription domain".

so you can ask counterpart to ADD the new net into VPN (as you will do at your endpoint), or simply NAT some address from 192.168.33.0/24 into 192.168.37.0/24

in case 192.168.33.0/24 is coming from another VPN you can only use NAT, but not redefinition of encr-domain.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you explain me how to configure the NAT rules ? PS : sorry for the poor details, I'm french my english is terrible

Comment: about english : don't worry, am' italian